# R comparing two columns in the same dataset

Tags: r

How do i get the number of rows that matches my condition: value of column 1 is lower than value of column2 plus 1?

```
nrow(subset(dataset, column1 <= column2 + 1))
```

When i run this command i get the following warning:

> Warning message:
>   In Ops.factor(column2, 1) : ‘+’ not meaningful for factors

And when i Run:

```
nrow(subset(dataset, column1 <= column2))
```

I get:

> Warning message:
>   In Ops.factor(vg, (column2)) : ‘<=’ not meaningful for factors

Comment: `sum(dataset$column1 <= (dataset$column2 + 1))` should give you the number of value for which the condition is `TRUE`

Comment: ... and dataset[dataset$column1 <= (dataset$column2 + 1), ] will give you the rows.

Comment: Please also read this thread and try to give more details in your future questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: sum(dataset$column1 <= (dataset$column2 + 1)) returns me this: [1] NA
Warning message:
In Ops.factor(dataset$column2, 1) : ‘+’ not meaningful for factors

Answer (score 0):

Could you please share the data you are using?

If the column 2 has numeric values, try changing the column's class from factor to numeric. Same for the column 1.

Maybe something like this could work:

```
sum(as.numeric(as.character(dataset$column1)) <= (as.numeric(as.character(dataset$column2)) + 1))
```